# out of memory exception caused by looping over a linked list

Tags: java, android

The following innocient piece of code causes a memory leak I don't understand why. It appears to fall over when I call GetChangedLedObjects(). why

Is it possible it's genuinely needs more memory?

```
    public class StateMachine {
      private LED zone1 = new LED();
      private LED zone2 = new LED();
      private LED zone3 = new LED();
      private LED zone4 = new LED();
      private LED zone5 = new LED();
      private LED zone6 = new LED();
      private LED zone7 = new LED();
      private LED zone8 = new LED();
      private LED tamper = new LED();
      private LED sos = new LED();
      private LED unst = new LED();
      private LED pwr = new LED();
      private LED set = new LED();
      private LED abrt = new LED();
      private LED intr = new LED();
      private LED pa = new LED();

      private Message lcd = new Message();

      public void InitialiseStateMachine(Map < String, Button > buttonMap) {
        Button zone1 = buttonMap.getOrDefault("zone1", new Button());
        this.zone1.Id = zone1.Id;
        this.zone1.onStateDrawable = zone1.onState;
        this.zone1.offStateDrawable = zone1.offState;

        Button zone2 = buttonMap.getOrDefault("zone2", new Button());
        this.zone2.Id = zone2.Id;
        this.zone2.onStateDrawable = zone2.onState;
        this.zone2.offStateDrawable = zone2.offState;

        Button zone3 = buttonMap.getOrDefault("zone3", new Button());
        this.zone3.Id = zone3.Id;
        this.zone3.onStateDrawable = zone3.onState;
        this.zone3.offStateDrawable = zone3.offState;

        Button zone4 = buttonMap.getOrDefault("zone4", new Button());
        this.zone4.Id = zone4.Id;
        this.zone4.onStateDrawable = zone4.onState;
        this.zone4.offStateDrawable = zone4.offState;

        Button zone5 = buttonMap.getOrDefault("zone5", new Button());
        this.zone5.Id = zone5.Id;
        this.zone5.onStateDrawable = zone5.onState;
        this.zone5.offStateDrawable = zone5.offState;

        Button zone6 = buttonMap.getOrDefault("zone6", new Button());
        this.zone6.Id = zone6.Id;
        this.zone6.onStateDrawable = zone6.onState;
        this.zone6.offStateDrawable = zone6.offState;

        Button zone7 = buttonMap.getOrDefault("zone7", new Button());
        this.zone7.Id = zone7.Id;
        this.zone7.onStateDrawable = zone7.onState;
        this.zone7.offStateDrawable = zone7.offState;

        Button zone8 = buttonMap.getOrDefault("zone8", new Button());
        this.zone8.Id = zone6.Id;
        this.zone8.onStateDrawable = zone8.onState;
        this.zone8.offStateDrawable = zone8.offState;

        Button tamper = buttonMap.getOrDefault("tamper", new Button());
        this.tamper.Id = zone6.Id;
        this.tamper.onStateDrawable = tamper.onState;
        this.tamper.offStateDrawable = tamper.offState;

        Button sos = buttonMap.getOrDefault("sos", new Button());
        this.sos.Id = zone6.Id;
        this.sos.onStateDrawable = sos.onState;
        this.sos.offStateDrawable = sos.offState;

        Button unst = buttonMap.getOrDefault("unst", new Button());
        this.unst.Id = unst.Id;
        this.unst.onStateDrawable = unst.onState;
        this.unst.offStateDrawable = unst.offState;

        Button pwr = buttonMap.getOrDefault("pwr", new Button());
        this.pwr.Id = pwr.Id;
        this.pwr.onStateDrawable = pwr.onState;
        this.pwr.offStateDrawable = pwr.offState;

        Button set = buttonMap.getOrDefault("set", new Button());
        this.set.Id = set.Id;
        this.set.onStateDrawable = set.onState;
        this.set.offStateDrawable = set.offState;

        Button abrt = buttonMap.getOrDefault("abrt", new Button());
        this.abrt.Id = abrt.Id;
        this.abrt.onStateDrawable = abrt.onState;
        this.abrt.offStateDrawable = abrt.offState;

        Button intr = buttonMap.getOrDefault("intr", new Button());
        this.intr.Id = intr.Id;
        this.intr.onStateDrawable = intr.onState;
        this.intr.offStateDrawable = intr.offState;

        Button pa = buttonMap.getOrDefault("pa", new Button());
        this.pa.Id = pa.Id;
        this.pa.onStateDrawable = pa.onState;
        this.pa.offStateDrawable = pa.offState;
      }

      public boolean StateHasChanged() {
        boolean changed = false;
        LinkedList < LED > myList = getLedLinkedList();

        for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
          LED led = myList.get(i);
          if (led.updateRequired == true) {
            changed = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        return changed;
      }

      @NonNull
      private LinkedList < LED > getLedLinkedList() {
        LinkedList < LED > myList = new LinkedList < > ();
        myList.add(zone1);
        myList.add(zone2);
        myList.add(zone3);
        myList.add(zone4);
        myList.add(zone5);
        myList.add(zone6);
        myList.add(zone7);
        myList.add(zone8);
        myList.add(tamper);
        myList.add(sos);
        myList.add(unst);
        myList.add(pwr);
        myList.add(set);
        myList.add(abrt);
        myList.add(intr);
        myList.add(pa);
        return myList;
      }

      public LinkedList < LED > GetChangedLedObjects() {
        boolean changed = false;
        LinkedList < LED > myList = getLedLinkedList();

        for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
          LED led = myList.get(i);
          if (led.updateRequired == true) {
            myList.add(led);
          }
          led = null;
        }
        return myList;
      }

      public void SetZone1Status(boolean state) {
        if (state != this.zone1.onState) {
          this.zone1.onState = state;
          this.zone1.updateRequired = true;
        }
      }

      public Map < String, Boolean > GetZone1Status() {
        Map < String, Boolean > map = new HashMap < > ();
        map.put("state", this.zone1.onState);
        map.put("updateRequired", this.zone1.updateRequired);
        return map;
      }

      public void SetZone2Status(boolean state) {
        if (state != this.zone2.onState) {
          this.zone2.onState = state;
          this.zone2.updateRequired = true;
        }
      }
    }

public class LED {
    public boolean onState;
    public boolean updateRequired;
    public int Id;
    public Drawable onStateDrawable;
    public Drawable offStateDrawable;
}
```

Comment: Please show your exception's stack trace

Comment: You know that you have a lot unnecessarily repetitive code, right?

Answer (score 4):

From the provided code, it appears that there is a potential memory leak in the **GetChangedLedObjects** method due to the way you're updating the **myList** LinkedList. The method is intended to return a list of LED objects that have their **updateRequired** property set to **true**. However, instead of adding the LED objects meeting this condition to a new list, you are adding them back to the original list, causing a potential infinite loop and memory consumption.

Here's the corrected **GetChangedLedObjects** method:

```
public LinkedList<LED> GetChangedLedObjects() {
    LinkedList<LED> changedLedList = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<LED> myList = getLedLinkedList();

    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
        LED led = myList.get(i);
        if (led.updateRequired) {
            changedLedList.add(led); // Add the changed LED to the new list
        }
    }
    return changedLedList;
}
```

By making these changes, you prevent the original LinkedList from growing indefinitely and causing a memory leak.

Have fun!

Comment: Lol not enough sleep. That's funny. :doh

Comment: happens to the best :)

Answer (score 0):

As a reference, you can significantly reduce your code.

Utilize a *Map* to index the *LED* values.

```java
class StateMachine {
    Map<String, LED> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void InitialiseStateMachine(Map< String, Button> buttonMap) {
        String s;
        Button b;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
            b = buttonMap.getOrDefault(s = ("zone" + i), new Button());
            map.put(s, new LED(b.Id, b.onState, b.offState));
        }
        for (LED.Value v : LED.Value.values()) {
            b = buttonMap.getOrDefault(s = v.name().toLowerCase(), new Button());
            map.put(s, new LED(b.Id, b.onState, b.offState));
        }
    }

    public boolean StateHasChanged() {
        return map.values().stream().anyMatch(i -> i.updateRequired);
    }

    public LinkedList < LED > GetChangedLedObjects() {
        LinkedList<LED> c = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, LED> e : map.entrySet())
            if (e.getValue().updateRequired) c.add(e.getValue());
        return c;
    }

    public void SetZone1Status(boolean state) {
        LED led = map.get("zone1");
        if (state != led.onState) {
            led.onState = state;
            led.updateRequired = true;
        }
    }

    public Map < String, Boolean > GetZone1Status() {
        Map < String, Boolean > map = new HashMap< >();
        LED led = this.map.get("zone1");
        map.put("state", led.onState);
        map.put("updateRequired", led.updateRequired);
        return map;
    }

    public void SetZone2Status(boolean state) {
        LED led;
        if (state != (led = map.get("zone2")).onState) {
            led.onState = state;
            led.updateRequired = true;
        }
    }
}

class LED {
    enum Value { TAMPER, SOS, UNST, PWR, SET, ABRT, INTR, PA }
    public boolean onState, updateRequired;
    public int Id;
    public Drawable onStateDrawable, offStateDrawable;

    public LED(int id, Drawable onStateDrawable, Drawable offStateDrawable) {
        Id = id;
        this.onStateDrawable = onStateDrawable;
        this.offStateDrawable = offStateDrawable;
    }
}
```